# Can an EU country claim tax fees of an orphan pension refund of times where the affected person resided in another?

Tags: european-union, tax-law

Explanation at the example case:

Person `A` is an orphan and was moved from an EU country `X` to another EU country `Y`. Lately, after a few years his pension claims were successful and he has received a refund of all pension payments as he usually had received each month.

Unfortunately, the amount of the refund is as high as that it is obliged to taxing in `Y`. All requirements to claim the tax are fulfilled in country `Y` where Person `A` now resides and was moved to, although it is an orphan´s pension.

The problem now:

The corresponding tax authority of country `Y` claims the whole refund, although Person `A` did not even reside at that moment of time in the country nor had a bank account or anything else in `Y`.

It is important, because if the amount of money to be taxed would be subtracted by the amount of money from the monthly payments where Person `A` wasn´t in `Y`, Person `A` would not be obliged to declare the tax and with that tax-free for that refund.

Is it correct that `Y` can claim the parts of the amount of monthly payments (which are part of the refund) although Person `A` did not even reside at that moment in `Y` or is there any EU law which prevents that doing?

---

Further annotations:

- It was not taxed in `X` - the country of origin - yet.
- Both countries, `X` and `Y` are members of the European Union.
- The age of Person `A` of the year of the tax claim and the refund were 19.

Comment: Income tax laws are **National** laws, so the laws of countries X and Y apply. In general income tax is paid in your country of residence.  [Double taxation](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/taxes/double-taxation/index_en.htm) agreements exist between countries where claims from both countries exist.

Comment: I have assumed that you are a German speaker and wrote "become" to translate *bekommen.* However, English "become" translates *werden.*  If I have misunderstood, please edit the question to correct it.

Comment: @phoog Where did I wrote *"become"*?

Comment: You wrote "Lately, after a few years his pension claims were successful and he has become a refund of all pension payments as he usually had become each month."

Comment: @phoog Ah, yes. You´re right. Didn´t mind your edit. Me fool. This is embarassing because most of the times I don´t do this mistake. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I just have to mention my favorite story about the waitress in Hamburg who told me (in English) that if I ordered from a particular section of the menu I would become a salad.

Comment: @phoog Yes. :-) I know jokes of that kind a lot. It´s embarrassing that I did this mistake. I guess, it was because I´m personally involved and was with my mind somewhere else as I posted this question here to find a might existing EU law while doing the tax declaration.